# Chrome not setting cookiebut firefox does

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-chrome, cookies

I am doing a react + node project with google sign in.
Have already configured cors with

```
{
 origin: 'http://localhost:3000', 
 credentials: true
}
```

and using fetch with

```
credentials: 'include'
```

also I am using cookie parser middleware
and I am setting a cookie which is being sent with response header but chrome is not setting the cookie while firefox does save it.

I have seen other answers indicating that its the bug in chromium where it does not set cookies set by
localhost but a cookie named "G_AUTHUSER_H" is set with domain "localhost".

The cookie was once set but I deleted it to test again. But now chrome does not set the cookie.